# How to select nth element of a locator using data-testid attribute

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

How can I select nth element of a css locator using data-testid attribute? I'm using cypress but cannot use eq([index]) method. (xpath is not an option)

Example locator, it's a list and I have multiple elements with data-testid="frame":

```
<div data-component="layout" data-testid="frame" class="tzhgczFPvds">TEST</div>
```

Example code where I need to use the locators (sourceitem, targetitem):

```
describe('Dragtest', () => {
  it('should dragndrop', () => {
    cy.visit('/yourpage')

    cy.get('.sourceitem').drag('.targetitem', options)
  })
})
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you use `.eq()` ?

Comment: because the plugin requires the locator only, the drag function doesn't recognize .eq() unfortunately. Xpath is not working without plugin, I have no unique css locator, only data-testid attributes on these elements..

Answer (score 5):

The nth element can be queried by moving `.eq(n)` inside the selector.

The `:eq()` is a jQuery selector syntax equivalent to `cy.get(selector).eq(2)`

```js
cy.get(`div.sourceitem:eq(2)`)          -- drop 3rd source
  .drag('.targetitem:eq(4)', options)   -- to 5th target
```

Ref [:eq() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> **Description**: Select the element at index n within the matched set

It is valid in any selector used by Cypress commands.

Comment: Thanks! I added the example of my locators, does it work with attributes? I tried ['data-testid="frame"']:eq(2) but no luck.

Comment: So, if you've not done very much testing - the trick is to try it on a simple piece of HTML, say an unordered list or a select with options. You should find that it works fine.